# Which version should I choose when I want to use Ember.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ember.js

I am currently considering using ember.js as my mvc solution.

I have learnt Version 1.10. It is merely a js mvc framework. 
But now Version 1.11 has released with huge modification. It is now more like a web container.

With Version 1.10, one can use it with Express(node.js) or JavaEE container. These back-end solutions are mature and familiar to me.

However, with Version 1.11, I think it is more like a standalone application. No additional back-end is needed.(Actually, It looks like one has to implement the backend logic inside the ember app.)

I currently haven't used Emberjs in any production yet. I am aware of that things can be more complicated when switch from study project to productional project.

So I wish people with emberjs production experience can give some advises. I have following enquiries.

1. Is Version 1.10 + Express(or Java EE) a good combination for production? Is 1.10 a reliable version? Is it adequate? What is the most difficult part while adopting to this methodology?
2. Is Version 1.11 a reliable platform, in perspective of a web container? Compared with the methodology above(1.10+Express or Java EE)， what are the strengths and drawbacks of Version 1.11?
3. Other tips or considerations of using Emberjs are appreciated as well!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ember.js has *always* been for writing standalone applications that communicate with a server via HTTP and JSON. This is not a change between 1.10 and 1.11.

In 1.11 we updated the guides to reflect the community's adoption of a standard build tool ([ember-cli](http://www.ember-cli.com/)). This build tool is not a replacement for your particular backend technology. You will still develop Ember.js as a stand-alone application and still need to develop a HTTP API service in the backend language and framework of your choice.

Because Ember.js adheres to [Semver](http://semver.org/), you do not need to adopt ember-cli as a build tool until Ember.js 2.0. All versions of Ember.js in the 1.x series will continue to operate in the style you originally learned. No new features require ember-cli.